# Is a migration from MySQL 5.5 to MariaDB 10 on cPanel possible?

Tags: mysql, cpanel, mariadb

I currently host around 400 websites and would like to migrate from MySQL 5.5 to MariaDB 10. The server is running WHM/cPanel 11.58 (CloudLinux).

I see the option to change the installation but, before I go ahead and do it, I would like to know whether it's a "straightforward" process. I am struggling to find any information online that is clear cut and explains whether MySQL databases/tables are compatible 100% with MariaDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to upgrade it but I will suggest you first upgrade your mysql version to 5.6 and then upgrade it to MariaDB, Also before upgrading your mysql verison I will suggest you please take backup of your all databases in .sql format.